# C++/Qt Problem with QLineEdit: Cannot get text

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to input an API key from the user but the string is always empty. The code is as follows:

```
    QObject::connect(ui->apiKeySubmit, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(getApikey()));
```

---

```
void MainWindow::getApiKey() {
    key = ui->apiEdit->text();
}
```

`key` is a QString and a private member of the class MainWindow

---

```
//I always get this message
    if(key == "") {
        QMessageBox* message = new QMessageBox(this);
        message->setText("Please enter an API key");
        message->exec();
    }
    multipart->append(partParameter("apikey",key));
```

---

And the part of mainwindow.ui with those widgets is as follows:

```
<widget class="QLineEdit" name="apiEdit">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>160</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>181</width>
      <height>26</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="inputMask">
     <string notr="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string notr="true"/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="apiKeySubmit">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>160</x>
      <y>90</y>
      <width>181</width>
      <height>26</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Submit</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
```

Comment: Please post a minimal, compilable example and not just fragments of your code.

Answer (score 2):

I had a typo, getApikey() instead of getApiKey(), should've looked at the code more carefully before posting the question.